# Modifying the font, textColor of Closed Caption in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avplayer

We are using an AVPlayer to display a video stream and closed caption text. Is there any way to modify the font, text color and other attributes of the closed caption (CC) text displayed? I looked at the AVPlayer documentation and it seems the only control available is to turn CC On or Off.

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

iOS 6 introduced AVTextStyleRule which can be used to affect the attributes of subtitles. The documentation would appear to indicate that they also apply to closed captions, but this does not appear to be the case.

```
        AVTextStyleRule *rule = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc]initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
                             (id)kCMTextMarkupAttribute_RelativeFontSize : @(200),
                             (id)kCMTextMarkupAttribute_ForegroundColorARGB : @[ @1, @1, @0, @0 ]}];

    playerItem.textStyleRules = @[rule];
```

See [this tutorial on using WebVTT in HLS](http://cimapps.tumblr.com/post/30659660952/webvtt-ios) for details on subtitling

Comment: I have tried this; it does not work for CEA 608/708 closed captioning but it does work for subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

From looking through the API I don't see a way to achieve this. Theoretically, the captions should be displayed in some sort of UIView implementation like UILabel. If this is the the case, you could try modifying the appearance of UILabel prior to establishing your player.

Let me know if this does anything:

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFontSize:20];
[[UILabel appearance] setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: How do I extract the CC text and display it to a label? We are getting our streams via HTTP live streaming.

Comment: You aren't extracting the CC text and creating your own label. Because that cc text is encapsulated by the AVPlayer we can only try to set global appearance properties to affect how that text is rendered (if the AVPlayer uses a UILabel at all). I've modified the code a bit, go ahead and paste that bit of code in where you initialize your player and see if it affects the CC text at all.

Comment: No, the CC text is not being rendered in a label.

Comment: Note this will change all UILabel not just the subtitles, probably not the best solution. this works better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660855/shift-avplayer-captions-when-subview-overlaps-them

Answer (score 0):

Swift version for changing font size:

```
videoPlayer.currentItem?.textStyleRules = [AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [kCMTextMarkupAttribute_RelativeFontSize as String : fontSize])!]
```