# Shift AVPlayer captions when subview overlaps them

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

Is it possible to shift the system captions that display for a video should a subview (non-native, custom player controls) appear over them? The captions displayed are text WebVTT captions.

On certain screen sizes, when I shift to landscape, our custom seek bar controls overlap captions that appear at the bottom of the player.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it's worth, this *is* possible. You need to access the AVPlayer's current item and set an AVTextStyleRule for it.

```
// currentPlayer is our instance of the AVPlayer
if let currItem = currentPlayer?.currentItem, 
  let rule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [kCMTextMarkupAttribute_OrthogonalLinePositionPercentageRelativeToWritingDirection as String: 93]) {
  // 93% from the top of the video
  currItem.textStyleRules = [rule]
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I am able to adjust the location of the subtitle with this. But do you know if we will be able to adjust it only when the player controls become visible?

Comment: This can also be done with modifiers on each line of text in the .vtt file, but in case you can’t change that on the fly, this is the correct answer. Thank you, Shaked Sayag!